# Batch automation script run in IE is failing due to proxy

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-processing, robotframework

I was trying to run multiple scripts using IE in Robot Framework. After around 35-40 test cases, IE browser instance is not getting launched due to a proxy issue and I am getting the error: "`No browser is open`".

Before running the test cases, I have unchecked the proxy settings in IE. I am not sure how it is getting checked again in between.

Comment: What IE are you using? Do the individual tests work and only fail when you group them into a test suite?

Comment: Its internet explorer 11.Individual test cases are running fine but in suite I am getting this error

Comment: Perhaps you need to focus on the Browser again? Are you tearing down the Browser after each test?

Comment: I am using the command close browser at the end of my test case.

Comment: I have never had any luck with the IE WebDriver. It is so unstable and barely works the way you want it to. My only advice I can give is that you focus the browser again and then run the test suite / focus the browser throughout the test.

Comment: Thanks for the response @goralight .I disabled the proxy setting using regedit command and it worked .

Comment: Try below as well -

OperatingSystem.Set Environment Variable no_proxy 127.0.0.1